# How to add Post Aggregation value fields as Metric in Druid io

Tags: java, druid

I am using druid io 0.9.0. I am trying to add a post aggregation field as a metric spec. My Intention is to show the value of the post aggregation field  similar to how a metric (measures) are shown (in Druid io using Pivot).

My Druid io schema file is

```
    {
      "dataSources" : {
        "NPS1112" : {
          "spec" : {
            "dataSchema" : {
              "dataSource" : "NPS1112",
              "parser" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "parseSpec" : {
                  "timestampSpec" : {
                    "column" : "timestamp",
                    "format" : "auto"
                  },
                  "dimensionsSpec" : {
                    "dimensions" : ["dimension1","dimension2","dimension3"],
                     "dimensionExclusions" : [
                      "timestamp",
                      "OverallRating",
                      "DeliveryTimeRating",
                      "ItemQualityRating",
                      "isPromoter",
                      "isDetractor"
                    ]
                  },
                  "format" : "json"
                }
              },
              "granularitySpec" : {
                "type" : "uniform",
                "segmentGranularity" : "hour",
                "queryGranularity" : "none"
              },
             "aggregations" : [
             { "type" : "count", "name" : "rows"},
             { "type" : "doubleSum", "name" : "CountOfPromoters", "fieldName" : "isPromoter" },
             { "type" : "doubleSum", "name" : "CountOfDetractor", "fieldName" : "isDetractor" }
            ],
            "postAggregations" : [
            { "type"   : "arithmetic",
              "name"   : "PromoterPercentage",
              "fn"     : "/",
              "fields" : [
                   { "type" : "fieldAccess", "name" : "CountOfPromoters", "fieldName" : "CountOfPromoters" },
                   { "type" : "fieldAccess", "name" : "rows", "fieldName" : "rows" }
                  ]
             },
             { "type"   : "arithmetic",
              "name"   : "DetractorPercentage",
              "fn"     : "/",
              "fields" : [
                   { "type" : "fieldAccess", "name" : "CountOfDetractor", "fieldName" : "CountOfDetractor" },
                   { "type" : "fieldAccess", "name" : "rows", "fieldName" : "rows" }
                  ]
             },
             { "type"   : "arithmetic",
              "name"   : "NPS",
              "fn"     : "-",
              "fields" : [
                   { "type" : "fieldAccess", "name" : "PromoterPercentage", "fieldName" : "PromoterPercentage" },
                   { "type" : "fieldAccess", "name" : "DetractorPercentage", "fieldName" : "DetractorPercentage" }
                  ]
             }
             ],
              "metricsSpec" : [
                {
                  "type" : "count",
                  "name" : "CountOfResponses"
                },
                {
                  "type" : "fieldAccess",
                  "name" : "CountOfPromoters"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ioConfig" : {
              "type" : "realtime"
            },
            "tuningConfig" : {
              "type" : "realtime",
              "maxRowsInMemory" : "10000",
              "intermediatePersistPeriod" : "PT10M",
              "windowPeriod" : "PT10M"
            }
          },
          "properties" : {
            "task.partitions" : "1",
            "task.replicants" : "1"
          }
        }
      },
      "properties" : {
        "zookeeper.connect" : "localhost",
        "druid.discovery.curator.path" : "/druid/discovery",
        "druid.selectors.indexing.serviceName" : "druid/overlord",
        "http.port" : "8200",
        "http.threads" : "4"
      }
    }
```

My Code for sending the fields using java client.

```
          final Map<String,Object> obj = new HashMap<String, Object>();

          obj.put("timestamp", new DateTime().toString());

          obj.put("OverallRating", (ran.nextInt(high-low) + low));
          obj.put("DeliveryTimeRating", (ran.nextInt(high-low) + low));
          obj.put("ItemQualityRating", (ran.nextInt(high-low) + low));
          obj.put("isPromoter", ((ran.nextInt(high-low) + low)%2) == 0 ? 1 : 0);
          obj.put("isDetractor", ((ran.nextInt(high-low) + low)%2) == 0 ? 1 : 0);

          obj.put("dimension1", "dimension1-"+ (ran.nextInt(high-low) + low));
          obj.put("dimension2", "dimension2-"+ (ran.nextInt(high-low) + low));
          obj.put("dimension3", "dimension3-"+ (ran.nextInt(high-low) + low));
```

Can any one point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that in your ingestion spec (I'd actually want to know if we could!), but you can add your post aggregations in the pivot configuration. From what I understand post aggregations are actually part of a druid query.

First, generate a config file with pivot:

```
pivot --druid your.druid.broker.host:8082 --print-config --with-comments > config.yaml
```

Then modify the config.yaml. The syntax is quite different, but you can quite easily combine aggregators. Here's the example provided in the config.yaml file:

```
  # This is the place where you might want to add derived measures (a.k.a Post Aggregators).
  #
  # Here are some examples of possible derived measures:
  #
  # - name: ecpm
  #   title: eCPM
  #   expression: $main.sum($revenue) / $main.sum($impressions) * 1000
  #
  # - name: usa_revenue
  #   title: USA Revenue
  #   expression: $main.filter($country == 'United States').sum($revenue)
```

Finally, run pivot with the `--config` flag

```
pivot --config config.yaml
```

Hope it helps a bit! :)